# SQL table column need to change datetime format to date

Tags: sql, date, datetime, ssms, dateadd

I have a column in a table with this format '2017-05-09 14:52:32.000' I would appreciate a way to convert it to a date format like MM/DD/YYYY
I have tried with:

```
select DATEADD(column, DATEDIFF(column, 0, getdate()), 0)
  FROM table
```

but I get this error:

> Column is not a recognized datediff option.

I've also tried another way and failed.

Please advise.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: "*FOO* is not a recognized datediff option" is the exact wording of the error message in SQL Server.

Comment: Have you checked your dbms documentation??? You can't write code in whatever format you want, and expect your dbms to understand and execute it.

Comment: I use SSMS. Ross gave the answer that worked. Thanks Ross.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming from the error message you reported that you're on SQL Server.

In SQL Server, the DATEADD and DATEDIFF functions take a "date part" as the first argument: YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND or MILLISECOND:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, [COLUMN], GETDATE()), [COLUMN]) 
FROM [TABLE]
```

might be want what you want.

However,

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [COLUMN]) AS [COLUMNDATE]
```

Might be even easier.